# Where in the Macross franchise was the fall of the Protoculture detailed?

Tags: macross

Speaking specifically about the original Japanese franchise(s), rather than *Robotech*...

I have seen various online sources saying that the Protoculture were the progenitor species for many of the races followed in the franchise. That they had a mighty empire when the galaxy was young and that it fell after the Protoculture tried to tap into a new energy source that brought them into conflict with another race made of energy.

Where in the franchise is this detailed?

For example, if I wanted to see or read about it, which manga volumes, episodes, novels, or video games would I need to buy?

If there is more than one conflicting source from a different continuity, then which one is canon to the original animated series of *Macross*?